# How can I add Social Provider like Google, Apple sign in `withAuthenticator` in Amplify AWS?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

I have checked the official docs but there is no mention of how can I add social providers like Google, Apple sign in `withAuthenticator` clearly.

I have also applied custom UI changes and followed documentation so that I can see changes in UI.

According to [Docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/customui/q/platform/js/#customize-withauthenticator-hoc)

If you would like to add custom styling to the UI components you can pass a custom theme object as a parameter to the withAuthenticator HOC using the instructions above:

```
export default withAuthenticator(App, false, [], null, MyTheme);
```

Now, I also need to add social providers like Google, Apple sign-in. But I can't find in documentation how can I do so?

Comment: Did you read [Social sign-in (OAuth)](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js/)?

Comment: Yes, I have done all those things mentioned in it. But I can't find a way to integrate social provider buttons with `withAuthenticator `.

Comment: Looks like there are updated [docs](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator#styling).

Comment: I have tried but it's not working. I guess this is for `react.js` not for `react-native`? ```<Authenticator socialProviders={["apple", "google"]}><AppNavigator /></Authenticator>```

Comment: @HarshMishra did you found the solution? even i have the same question

Answer (score 0):

No Changes to withAuthenticator function

Update Cognito User Pool with Sign In Experience to Identity Provider ( Google , Amazon etc )

Update You Project File auth/resource.tsx with same provider you enabled in User Pool and define callback Urls and Logout Urls

You are Done